# In R, how to efficiently de-dupe a data.frame while processing the duplicates?

Tags: r, dataframe

(The title of the question is terrible, I'm sorry. I was having a hard time finding a pithy way to express it.)

I have a "tall" data.frame that I have compiled. It looks like this:

```
id | rating
-----------
3  | 5.5
4  | 6
4  | 7
5  | 3
5  | 5
6  | 7.5
7  | 9
...
```

I want to turn that into this:

```
id | avg rating
-----------
3  | 5.5
4  | 6.5
5  | 4
6  | 7.5
7  | 9
...
```

I don't just want to remove duplicates. I want to take the rows that have the same duplicate id, remove the duplicates, but update the rating field to be the average.

I'm not sure how to go about this. I'm not even sure whether I should be modifying the original data frame or instead creating a new one with the modified data.

(Note: I think a good answer would be a bit agnostic to the specifics of the operation. Like, if I wanted to do something similar but instead have the resulting rating column be a sum or a count, hopefully your answer would apply to those situations as well.)

Comment: Just use `aggregate` with `mean`.  I.e. `aggregate(rating ~ id, data, mean)`

Comment: @RichScriven Wow, every once in a while R makes things stupidly easy. Thank you! I can't quite tell from the documentation, can aggregate take multiple functions? Like, if I wanted to both take the mean and round, for example.

Comment: Figured it out: anonymous functions passed to the FUN argument.

Answer (score 1):

You also have the option to use SQL language is you are familiar with it.
You will require the sqldf package `library(sqldf)`

`` sqldf("
      select id, avg(rating) `avg_rating`
      from your_data
      group by id
      ") ``

Answer (score 0):

A version using `dplyr` and including a sum example.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(avg_rating = mean(rating),
            sum_rating = sum(rating))
```